# Ограничить выбор чекбоксов, в имеющемся скрипте по замене

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, необходимо в форме ограничить выбор чекбоксов до 3х. Раньше пользовался таким скриптом:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length >= 3){
    $('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').attr('disabled', true);
} else{
    $('input[type=checkbox]:disabled').attr('disabled', false);
}
```

Всё это работает отлично.

Но появилась необходимость заменить стандартный вид чекбоксов на картинки, нашел такой код, все работает по замене отлично. Но перестало работать ограничение на чекбоксы.

```
// add/remove checked class
$(".image-checkbox").each(function(){
if($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').first().attr("checked")){
    $(this).addClass('image-checkbox-checked');
}else{
    $(this).removeClass('image-checkbox-checked');
}  });


// sync the input state
$(".image-checkbox").on("click", function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass('image-checkbox-checked');
    var $checkbox = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
    $checkbox.prop("checked",!$checkbox.prop("checked"));

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Понимаю, что знающие люди найдут проблему на раз. Но уровень моего JS - найти и вставить скрипт не более. Надеюсь на помощь. Спасибо.

Comment: Добавьте проверку возле установки а именно возле
 $checkbox.prop("checked",!$checkbox.prop("checked"));

Comment: Где именно, можете уточнить? Спасибо.

Comment: За Js будущее... рекомендую его изучить, хорошая инвестиция времени

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полный код не видел но если судить по тому что показали то вот так:

```
// add/remove checked class
$(".image-checkbox").each(function(){
if($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').first().attr("checked")){
    $(this).addClass('image-checkbox-checked');
}else{
    $(this).removeClass('image-checkbox-checked');
}  });


// sync the input state
$(".image-checkbox").on("click", function(e){

    var $checkbox = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
  if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length < 3){
    $(this).toggleClass('image-checkbox-checked');
    $checkbox.prop("checked",!$checkbox.prop("checked"));
  }else{
    // тут проверка на выключение одного из этих трех checkbox, если включен  
     // выключить иначе игнор
        if($checkbox.prop("checked")){
          $(this).toggleClass('image-checkbox-checked'); 
          $checkbox.prop("checked",""));
        }else{

        }
   }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```